# meross Smart switch wiring

Tags: smart-switch

having trouble with the wiring of a meross smart switch install. Smart switch on left controls chandelier and the right is a two way switch. [image][image]

Comment: I see a green ground going to a black normally hot or switched hot. Problem #1. Can you provide a better photo of the back of the box so we can see the wire connections to figure out where the black and brown should connect. That green should connect to the bare wire ground that is connected to the back of the box.

Comment: Added a pic hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your black and brown reversed. The ground green wire is connected to a black and to the box so other than color it is correct. 
The copper hanging out from the wire nut at the black brown, 2 blacks and a brown is that making a good connection? If it is I would put the black on the always hot and the brown on the hot to the light, I looked online for a schematic and only found black to black and brown to brown. That did not help. 
Since your original switch only had 2 terminals on , off control if wired the same way reverse them so the switch is being powered and it should work.

Comment: Good eye on the miscolored ground wire. OP that is a showstopper, peel the insulation off that wire!

Answer (score 1):

### Try swapping the two blacks

Your neutral and ground connections check out... Although the black colored ground pigtail is illegal, but can easily be corrected by stripping the insulation.

The issue is the hot wires. Old school switches don't care.   But being a powered switch, the switch cares very much which black wire is supply (Line) and which powers the load. All its electronics need to sit between Line and Neutral.    50/50 chance, if you wire it up so the electronics are between LOAD and neutral, it can't power up.  Normally you mustn't experiment with wire hookups because many combinations work but are dangerous; but swapping among *hot* wires on a *switch* is pretty safe.

Also, if part of the smart switch's yoke is metal (i.e. The parts the screws go through), you don't need to wire the ground on a metal box.  It'll happen through the screws.